# Laplace Transform Piecewise Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image]

I've never seen these types of bounds on a piecewise function of a Laplace transform before, can someone help explain how to solve this problem, particularly the Laplace transform of g(t)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you can write the piecewise function using the Heaviside Unit Step function as:

$$g(t)  = t - (t-3) u_3(t) = t - (t-3) u(t-3)$$

Can you now continue?

**Update**

To find the [*Laplace Transform*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) of $g(t)$, we can rewrite it as:

$$g(t) = t - (t-3) u(t-3) = t + 3 u(t-3) - t u(t-3)$$

Using formula $28$ in the table, we have:

$$\mathscr{L} (g(t)) = \mathscr{L}(t) + 3 \mathscr{L}u(t-3) - \mathscr{L}((t+3)u(t-3)) = \dfrac{1}{s^2} + \dfrac{3}{s}e^{-3s} - \left(\dfrac{1}{s^2} + \dfrac{3}{s}\right) e^{-3s}$$

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your response. I should have stated earlier that I already got to that step, I just need help doing a Laplace transform on what you just posted. Could you help?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This will really help me on my final.

Comment: I was working on other problems until I got a chance to fully see the answer to this. Why does tu(t-3) turn into (t+3)u(t-3) when you do the Laplace transform?

Comment: Thank you so much. It all makes sense now! For real this time! (;

Comment: Should I delete my comment below the other A's answer?

Comment: Will delete. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulGould The presented solution gives several unnecessary steps that complicate the whole process. You can see it if you simplify the final answer (two terms cancel)