# Rewrite piecewise function to Heaviside - step-by-step

Tags: functions

I'm trying to learn how to rewrite piecewise function in terms of Heaviside func.

I've found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777593/laplace-transform-piecewise-function), with a pretty simple piecewise function:

$$
g(t) = 
\begin{cases}
t & \text{ if } t < 3\\
3 & \text{ if } t > 3
\end{cases}
$$

I've tried to rewrite it this way:
\begin{align}
g(t) &= t[t < 3] + 3[t>3]\\
&= t[\neg(t\geq 3)] + 3[t >3]\\
&= t[\neg(t-3\geq 0)] + 3[t-3 >0]\\
&= t(1-[t-3 \geq 0]) + 3[\neg(t-3 \leq 0)]\\
&= t(1-[t-3 \geq 0]) + 3[\neg(3-t \geq 0)]\\
&= t(1-[t-3 \geq 0]) + 3(1-[3-t \leq 0])\\
&= t(1-u(t-3)) + 3(1-u(3-t))\\
&= t - tu(t-3) + 3 - 3u(3-t)
\end{align}

In the answer there is the function rewritten in the form:
$$
g(t) = t - (t-3)u(t-3)
$$

And I can't figure out, what steps lead to this "solution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discontinuity is on $x=3$, then the Heaviside function should be centered on this point: $g(t)=a+b\,u(t-3)$. This function has a value of $0$ for $t<3$ and $1$ for $t>3$.

For $t<3$ we have $g(t)=a=t$, finding $g(t)=t+b\,u(t-3)$. Finally, imposing the condition for $t>3$, $g(t>3)=t+b=3$, finding $b=3-t$. To summarize the solution:
$$g(t)=t+(3-t)u(t-3)$$

Actually you got really close to the solution. In line 4 I read $t(1-u(t-3))+3u(t-3)$. Grouping the terms together, the final solution is found.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really elegant. But still, could you, please, look at my solution and tell me, what I'm missing there? I'm really interested in improving my ideas :-)

Comment: I think you got actually really close to the final solution. From your last line, and applying that $3-3u(3-t)=3u(t-3)$ you obtain the final expression. So, there is nothing worng or missing in your result: it was just a question of simplification!

Comment: Ok, now I'm going to sound really stupid... But how did you manage to reverse `3-t` to `t-3` and maintain $\geq 0$ relation? Could you, please, write some in-between step?

Comment: there is never a stupid question :) I have used the property of the Heaviside function under the reversing of its argument: $u(-t)=1-u(t)$.  I guess it is the same property you have used for reverting the $t<3$ to $t>3$, for example between lines 3 and 4 of your solution. Actually your problem was somehow solved on line 4, where I read $t(1-u(t-3))+3u(t-3)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Add, please this explanation to your answer, so I can accept it ;-)

Comment: I added a small comment about your solution. I am happy that it is useful for you!